# Where is Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client on github?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have .NET Core library with framework set to `netstandard1.6`. In the library I want to use HttpClient's extension method `PostAsJsonAsync`, however I want to make sure this extension method ensures OK response. Something like:

```
httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
```

I am assuming whole ASP.NET Core code is on GitHub. Where would I find the codebase of `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` on GitHub? I could not find it here: https://github.com/aspnet

Comment: This library isn't part of ASP.NET Core, so you won't find it on the linked repository. Try the repositories of ASp.NET MVC (should be on codeplex)

Comment: @Tseng if its not part of the .net core project then will i be able to use it in .Net Core library with framework `netstandard1.6`? or for .Net Core `PostAsJsonAsync` extension method is available in different library?

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/ See the dependencies. It has `portable-net45-win8-win81-wpa8-wpa81` profile, so in theory it should work, when you add `"import" : [ "portable-net45-win8-win81" ]` to the project.json

Comment: @Tseng anyway, is its source-code anywhere to be found on GitHub?

Comment: @Shimmy i dont think there is one yet. Also if there is one it would be `Microsoft.AspNetCore.`..i think they started using `AspnetCore` naming convention for all asp.net core libraries. I created my own extension methods

Answer (score 2):

`Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` is unfortunately an unclear name here. The [NuGet description for the package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/) explains it like this:

> This package adds support for formatting and content negotiation to System.Net.Http. It includes support for JSON, XML, and form URL encoded data.

If you look at the package more closely, you will notice that it does not contain any assembly called `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client`. Instead, it contains `System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll` which includes utilities within the `System.Net.Http` namespace.

With that information, it’s not too difficult to find the source for this package, since the link on NuGet is actually correct.

You can find the source within the [aspnet/AspNetWebStack repository](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/tree/master/src/System.Net.Http.Formatting).